# Problem in finding examples of linear operators.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the example of two linear operators $T$ and $U$ such that $TU = O$ but $UT \neq O$.  But I fail to find out proper example.Please help me in finding the example.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think geometrically. Consider for instance an orthogonal projection $P$ onto the $y$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a $90^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation $R$. Then it takes a simple drawing to convince oneself that $P(RP)=0$ (first $P$ maps the plane to a vertical line; then $R$ maps this line into a horizontal line; and finally $P$ squishes the horizontal line to the zero vector) but $(RP)P = RP^2 = RP \neq 0$. In terms of matrices, $P = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $R = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Alex your example is fantastic.It's very easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, if our space is $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard basis, then
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\quad U = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
fulfill $TU = 0, UT\neq 0$.

It's a good exercice to see what these two operations do geometrically, and why $TU = 0, UT\neq 0$ is true from that point of view.

Comment: Arthur it is given $UT$ is not a zero operator.But in your example $UT$ becomes a zero operator.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. No, $UT = U$.

Comment: Sorry Arthur I have done a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: No problem. Everyone does mistakes from time to time.